# Constant time test for first element in intrusive rbtree

Tags: c++, boost

How can I efficiently tell if an element is at the beginning of an intrusive set or rbtree?  I would like to define a simple function `prev` that returns a pointer to the previous item in a tree, or `nullptr` if there is no previous item.  An analogous `next` function is easy to write, using `iterator_to` and comparing to `end()`.  However, there is no equivalent `reverse_iterator_to` function that would allow me to compare to `rend()`.  Moreover, I specifically do not want to compare to `begin()`, because that's not constant time in a red-black tree.

One thing that certainly seems to work is decrementing an iterator and comparing it to `end()`.  That works fine with the implementation, but I can find no support for this in the documentation.  What's the best way to implement `prev` in the following minimal working example?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/intrusive/set.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::intrusive;

struct foo : set_base_hook<> {
  string name;
  foo(const char *n) : name(n) {}
  friend bool operator<(const foo &a, const foo &b) { return a.name < b.name; }
};

rbtree<foo> tree;

foo *
prev(foo *fp)
{
  auto fi = tree.iterator_to(*fp);
  return --fi == tree.end() ? nullptr : &*fi;
}

int
main()
{
  tree.insert_equal(*new foo{"a"});
  tree.insert_equal(*new foo{"b"});
  tree.insert_equal(*new foo{"c"});
  for (foo *fp = &*tree.find("c"); fp; fp = prev(fp))
    cout << fp->name << endl;
}
```

**Update:** Okay, so what I was missing, which is probably what sehe was getting at indirectly, is that in STL begin() is actually guaranteed to be constant-time.  So even though a generic red-black tree requires log(n) time to find the minimum element, an STL map doesn't--an STL std::map implementation is required to cache the first element.  And I think the point sehe is making is that even though boost is not documented, it is fair to assume that boost::intrusive containers behave sort of like STL containers.  Given that assumption, it is perfectly fine to say:

```
foo *
prev(foo *fp)
{
  auto fi = tree.iterator_to(*fp);
  return fi == tree.begin() ? nullptr : &*--fi;
}
```

As the comparison to tree.begin() shouldn't be too costly.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the reverse-iterator from `iterator_to`.

> Also, note that [there is `rbtree<>::container_from_iterator(iterator it)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/boost/intrusive/rbtree.hpp) so you don't have to have a "global" state for your `prev` function.

---

You can just create the corresponding reverse_iterator. You'll have to +1 the iterator to get the expected address:
[image]

So my take on this would be (**bonus:** without memory leaks):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f33c56e7884bc392)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/intrusive/set.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace boost::intrusive;

struct foo : set_base_hook<> {
    std::string name;
    foo(char const* n) : name(n) {}

    bool operator<(const foo &b) const { return name < b.name; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<foo> v;
    v.emplace_back("a");
    v.emplace_back("b");
    v.emplace_back("c");

    using Tree = rbtree<foo>;

    Tree tree;
    tree.insert_unique(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (auto key : { "a", "b", "c", "missing" })
    {
        std::cout << "\nusing key '" << key << "': ";
        auto start = tree.iterator_to(*tree.find(key));

        if (start != tree.end()) {
            for (auto it = Tree::reverse_iterator(++start); it != tree.rend(); ++it)
                std::cout << it->name << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Which prints

```
using key 'a': a 
using key 'b': b a 
using key 'c': c b a 
using key 'missing':
```

Comment: You didn't implement a `prev` function (my actual question), though your solution suggests using `Tree::reverse_iterator(tree.iterator_to(fp))`.  Both that and my `prev` function work, but I can't find support for either of them in the boost documentation.  In particular, the relevant [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/intrusive/rbtree.html) states only that it is implementation-defined.  Does boost offer any "normative" description of iterator behavior?  Also, is there a guarantee that `rend()` is constant time, since in STL `rend().base()` must be log time?

Comment: The implicit conversion from reverse-iterator to base iterator is documented here e.g.: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator. I agree it's a convention. But many things about many libraries are not documented in that sense. It makes sense that a library that promises standard-library compatible containers adheres to the iterator requirements and conventions from that standard-library.

Comment: I don't know about complexity guarantees of hand. That is probably answered elsewhere, and could otherwise be a nice question in it's own right

Comment: Now I'm confused.  Is a `std::reverse_iterator<boost::intrusive::rbtree<foo>::iterator>` the same as a `boost::intrusive::rbtree<foo>::reverse_iterator`?  What basis is there for assuming those are the same types?

Comment: Nobody said that. Assuming that would be both unreasonable and unnecessary. I answered your question why such things would not be documented more explicitly